# Magento Payment transaction failed. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm getting this error in my Magento install more and more often.

```
**Payment transaction failed.**
**Reason**
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '38754-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

**Checkout Type**
onepage
```

Im sorry but I haven't got more info to share. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: have any product with entity_id 38754???

Comment: Yes 38754 but not 38754-0-1. This is not the only product it happens with.

Comment: it should be issue with dropdown and multi select attribute value of those products

Comment: Any idea of how to fix?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No. Do you have the same issue?

Comment: yes I do. what extensions do you have?

Comment: There is no second 38754-0-1 item because that is not possible. This error states that Magento tried to insert it, and then it failed. I've had this too on a order with a failed payment, so the first order failed because of the failed payment. My guess is that somehow the request to create this order is made twice, and at the same time the first insert fails because of that?

Comment: I had this same issue and could never get the order entity ids to match. I had to truncate all the tables to correct the problem. Unfortunately, if you're getting those errors in your log it means you're store is losing possible income, users are getting a popup error message with no idea why it didn't work.